# Looking for a set of benchmark applications which do not work well with modern CPU prefetchers, caches, branch predictors, etc

Tags: caching, x86-64, benchmarking, cpu-architecture, prefetch

Does anyone know where I can find a set of applications which are not amenable to modern micro-architecture sub-circuits which are present in CPUs, i.e. which do not benefit from modern micro-architecture designs. For example, a piece of code which has a lot of jumps may not work well with simplistic next in line instruction pre-fetchers. Basically I am looking for code examples for which the modern CPUs are not optimized for. I know the standard benchmarks such as matrix multiplication and all, but what I am looking for is small snippets of code which do not work well with a small subset of the micro-acrthitecture (small means one or two sub-circuits). Does anyone know where I can find such benchmarks?

Comment: GUPS RandomAccess might be worth looking at: https://icl.utk.edu/projectsfiles/hpcc/RandomAccess/

Comment: I was working recently on a toy Forth interpreter, and it occurred to me that the design is great for 1970s 8/16-bit CPUs, but not so great for 2020s 64-bit CPUs: every word executed involves an indirect jump, likely hard to predict and all dispatched from the same single instruction in the inner interpreter. And this happens every few instructions since words are very short.  Moreover, since the Forth return stack is likely to be separate from the CPU stack, you're not using normal call-return instructions, so stack-machine prediction will be defeated too.

Comment: For similar reasons, state machines might also be a good torture test.